# How can I switch focus after buffer split in emacs?

Tags: emacs, window, split, emacs23

I would like that after splitting the window (`C-x 3` or `C-x 2`) to be able to automatically get to cursor in the new opened buffer (the other than the current). How can I achieve this behavior ?

Comment: Morgan, my answer below can unfortunately lead to nasty side-effects, therefore I would like to retract it. Unfortunately, I cannot do so as long as it's the accepted answer. Could you please un-accept it, so I can delete it? Thanks.

Comment: C-x 4f isn't exactly what you're asking but it's a very convenient tip.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**!!!DO NOT USE THIS ANSWER!!!** -- as pointed out in the comments, advising `split-window` can lead to undesired side-effects.

I recommend **Bozhidar Batsov**'s answer instead.

---

Put the following in your .emacs file:

```
(defadvice split-window (after move-point-to-new-window activate)
  "Moves the point to the newly created window after splitting."
  (other-window 1))
```

Comment: As an observation, this would mess up ECB. At least in my setup.

Comment: If you have 2 vertical splitted buffers, and then do "org-schedule" in one (org) - you'll have a bug with Calendar buffer

Comment: @Sergey What kind of bug? Do you get a different behavior if you do the buffer switch manually after the split, instead of using the above code?

Comment: @Thomas, it opens Calendar, but the cursor is not visible in it's buffer, and it also replaces my org-file with 3 months of calendar  buffer content (so I have 2-3 not working Calendar buffers in the end)

Comment: retested, it appears to happen only after "split-window-right", when having 2(or more) buffers (one of them is org-file)

Comment: This breaks ispell-word (`M-$`), because it doesn't expect it to have the point in the ispell buffer it creates.  I think Bozhidar Batsov's solution of only changing the user keyboard shortcuts is a much better way.

Comment: @asmeurer I agree. Unfortunately, now that the answer was accepted, I cannot delete it :-( So, to everyone: only use the above solution if it fits your workflow.

Comment: This breaks anything, that has already implemented switching to created windows.
E.g. navigation in customizing groups.

Answer (score 69):

You can switch between buffers with `C-x o`. As to do that automatically I don't think there is an existing command for that.

Comment: Thanks for this. In my current setup I use S-<arrow_keys> to move around between the visible buffers, the automatic thing is what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 40):

You can do it like this:

```
(global-set-key "\C-x2" (lambda () (interactive)(split-window-vertically) (other-window 1)))
(global-set-key "\C-x3" (lambda () (interactive)(split-window-horizontally) (other-window 1)))
```

In Emacs 24.3.1 it works if you change the argument `1` for `0`.

Comment: Small typo here. It's `split-window-horizontally` instead of `split-window-horizonatally`. Tried to edit but don't have permissions.

Comment: Shouldn't it really be `split-window-right` and `split-window-below`?

Answer (score 3):

As well as splitting the frame manually with <kbd>C-x 2</kbd> or <kbd>C-x 3</kbd>, buffers are also automatically "popped-up" some times.  These are also not selected/active by default.

This can be fixed by changing the function used to split a window.  It's set to `split-window-sensibly` by default, but you can set it to your own function that calls `split-window-sensibly` and then selects the buffer.

Unfortunately, though, this has the side-effect of selecting the `*Completions*` buffer when you hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> in the minibuffer.  So, it's worth checking to see if the minibuffer is active and *not* switching in this case.  I'd bet there are other such undesirable scenarios as well.  I'll try to update this post as and when I find them.

```el
;; after splitting a frame automatically, switch to the new window (unless we
;; were in the minibuffer)
(setq split-window-preferred-function 'my/split-window-func)
(defun my/split-window-func (&optional window)
  (let ((new-window (split-window-sensibly window)))
    (if (not (active-minibuffer-window))
        (select-window new-window))))
```

(Works with Emacs 24.5.1.)

Answer (score 1):

My thought of when you would want to follow the window after a `split-window` was when it had the same buffer like in the following code:

```lisp
(defun split-window--select-window (orig-func &rest args)
  "Switch to the other window after a `split-window'"
  (let ((cur-window (selected-window))
        (new-window (apply orig-func args)))
    (when (equal (window-buffer cur-window) (window-buffer new-window))
      (select-window new-window))
    new-window))
(advice-add 'split-window :around #'split-window--select-window)
```

Simple

Answer (score 0):

C-x o will help you switch to the "other" buffer.