# Control Emacs behavior when splitting windows

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to customize the behavior when I split windows in Emacs:

I am always splitting because I want to view a separate buffer side-by-side with the one I'm currently editing.

I use `electric-buffer-list` (bound to <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd>) to navigate buffers.

I end up doing all of the following separately:

1. <kbd>C-x 3</kbd> to split horizontally.
2. <kbd>C-x o</kbd> to switch to the other window.
3. <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd> to invoke `electric-buffer-list` so I can select the buffer I want to view.

It seems like I should be able to write an Elisp function that will do all of this when I press <kbd>C-x 3</kbd>.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464738/how-can-i-switch-focus-after-buffer-split-in-emacs) which describes the focus switching part of the behavior that I want, but I don't understand how to extend that answer to achieve all of what I'm trying to do.

---

**Edit**: After reviewing @lawlist's post and debugging my syntax, I think I want to do something like this:

```
(defun split-right-and-buffer-list ()
  (interactive)
  (split-window-horizontally)
  (other-window 0)
  (electric-buffer-list 0))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 3") 'split-right-and-buffer-list)
```

This does everything I want, except that the buffer list that comes up only lists the current buffer, instead of the normal list of all buffers that I get when I invoke `electric-buffer-list` from its key binding.

Comment: Here is a similar thread where I modified `split-window-below` -- you can create your own function that splits horizontally:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19300409/2112489  You don't have to use a `defalias` -- i.e., you can just call your own revised function by name.  When in the window you want, you can use `switch-to-buffer` -- to move between windows we use `select-window . . .`

Comment: How about something like either of these links, which displays the standard buffer-list in a split-window -- you can modify the examples to display a different kind of buffer-list if you so choose.  This link is a left or right split example:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21544307/2112489  This link is a split-below example:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21591259/2112489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some very small modifications the function you came up with will do what you want:

```
(defun split-right-and-buffer-list ()
  (interactive)
  (split-window-horizontally)
  (other-window 1)
  (electric-buffer-list nil))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 3") 'split-right-and-buffer-list)
```

1. Passing `1` instead of `0` as an argument to `other-window` causes Emacs to select the new window created as a result of calling `split-window-horizontally`.
2. Passing `nil` instead of `0` as an argument to `electric-buffer-list` causes Emacs to show *all* buffers, not just *file-visiting* ones.

   The thing that can trip you up here is that this isn't mentioned in the documentation for `electric-buffer-list` (which doesn't include any information about the `ARG` it takes). But when you look at the [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/plain/lisp/ebuff-menu.el) of this command, you'll notice that it simply passes the value of the argument on to a function called `list-buffers-noselect` (and doesn't use it for anything else). The documentation of this function contains the missing piece of information mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind having custom commands to do what you want try the following functions

```lisp
(require 'ido)

(defun my-split-window-open-buffer-right (buffer)
  (interactive (list (ido-read-buffer "Please select a buffer: ")))
  (select-window (split-window-right))
  (switch-to-buffer buffer))

(defun my-split-window-open-buffer-below (buffer)
  (interactive (list (ido-read-buffer "Please select a buffer: ")))
  (select-window (split-window-below))
  (switch-to-buffer buffer))
```

Bind them to keys of you liking. I would prefer this over redefining/advising functions I have not written.